# FastAPI with APIRouter plugin system not working

Tags: python, plugins, fastapi, python-importlib

I'm trying to create a simple pluggable FastAPI application where plugins can add, or not, API endpoints

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

server.py

```
import importlib
import pkgutil
from pathlib import Path

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

PLUGINS_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("plugins")
app = FastAPI()


def import_module(module_name):
    """Imports a module by it's name from plugins folder."""
    module = f"plugins.{module_name}"
    return importlib.import_module(module, ".")


def load_plugins() -> list:
    """Import plugins from plugins folder."""
    loaded_apps = []
    for _, application, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([str(PLUGINS_PATH)]):
        module = import_module(application)
        print(
            f"Loaded app: {module.__meta__['plugin_name']} -- version: {module.__meta__['version']}"
        )
        loaded_apps.append(module)
    return loaded_apps


@app.get("/")
def main():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plugins = load_plugins()

    for plugin in plugins:
        """Register the plugins router."""
        if "router" in plugin.__dir__():
            app_router = plugin.router
            app.include_router(app_router)

    uvicorn.run("server:app", host="localhost", port=8000, reload=True)
```

And in my plugins folder I have:

The `plugins/non_api_plugin/__init__.py`:

```
__meta__ = {"plugin_name": "NON API plugin", "version": "0.0.1"}
```

The `plugins/<v1|v2>/__init__.py`

```
from .routes import routes as router

__meta__ = {"plugin_name": "API <v1|v2>", "version": "0.0.1"}
```

And routes.py files:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

routes = APIRouter(prefix="/<v1|v2>")


@routes.get("/")
def novels():
    return "Hello World from <v1|v2>"
```

When I run the server, the plugins are loaded and log their information, but the API endpoints are not loaded.

What I'm missing here? My best guess is that my plugin load system is wrong at some point.

Comment: What does "doesn't work as expected" mean?

Comment: @MatsLindh, the API endpoints are not added to the system, I edit the question for better understanding

Comment: Have you checked what the docs say about registered endpoints (`/docs`)? It seems like you're using the prefix both in your `include_router` and  where you're calling the api router constructor?

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes that's what I'm doing to check the endpoint, the `/docs` only shows the default endpoint added with `main` function, using the prefix in the constructor was just to try something, but I can remove it and have the same result

Comment: I update the server code to avoid redefinition of the prefix,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running your plugin registration code inside the code path that only runs when your script has the main context:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # plugin registration
```

Since you use this section to invoke `uvicorn`, uvicorn starts by itself and imports the module you're giving it. When *uvicorn* starts up, it imports your application and determines which endpoints are available - but now your own script is no longer the main context for the application, so anything inside the `__name__ == "__main__"` block will not run.

You'll see your expected behaviour as soon as you move the plugin registration block out of that scope:

```py
plugins = load_plugins()

for plugin in plugins:
    """Register the plugins router."""
    if "router" in plugin.__dir__():
        app_router = plugin.router
        app.include_router(app_router, prefix='/foo')  # I'd let the plugin name be the prefix here to avoid plugins using the same prefix

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("server:app", host="localhost", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Comment: So, as I understand I nees to have all routes loaded for all context not only in the `__main__` ??

Comment: `uvicorn` loads and launches the module you give it - loading it being the central part. If you wrap the plugin loading functionality inside a check to determine whether the script is being loaded directly by `python`, the plugin functionality will _not_ run when uvicorn launches your asgi application - effectively not registrering your plugins.